# Is there a way to restore a killed process?

Tags: linux, apache

I'm trying to start httpd on my web server but when I try to start it, I was getting "httpd (pd 10989) already running", so I killed the process in hopes httpd might start up. No luck.

Now I am getting:

```
    Starting HTTPD
    (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to 
    address [::]:9011
    (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to 
    address 0.0.0.0:9011
    no listening sockets available, shutting down
    AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

After I killed the process using:

```
    kill -9 10989
```

Is there a way to restore this process?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Probably unrelated, but don't use `kill -9` for normal operations. `SIGKILL` is for stopping misbehaving programs that aren't correctly responding to other signals.

Comment: That said, you may have kill a child process that was processing a request, not the parent process that listens for connections and forks children to handle a new request.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm seeing that SIGKILL would have been my best bet. There's no way to get it back then? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that the process you killed isn't the one tying up the socket address. Do something like `ps aux | grep httpd` to see if there are other `httpd` processes still running; that's probably the one that's using the address (and indicates that you probably don't need to start a new listener). In any case, this isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow; you may have better luck at superuser.com, unix.stackexchange.com, or even serverfault.com.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @chepner.

Comment: You can also use `lsof -i :9011` to see what processes have port 9011 open.

Comment: Anyway, you don't restore a killed process, you just run whatever script normally starts it up.

Comment: Okay. Three PID's came up when I ran sudo lsof -i :9011.

Comment: Okay, I removed those and it seems fine now.